# Speeding Up Python 3.4 Code

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I have a problem where I need to find the next largest palindrome after a given number, however I am running into problems with the runtime being over 1 second. Is there any way I can speed this code up?

```
inp = input()
if inp == '9' * len(inp):
    print('1' + ('0' * (len(inp) - 1)) + '1') #ran into a problem where 999 would give 9109
else:
num = list(inp)
oldnum = int(inp)
if len(num) % 2 == 0: #for even length numbers
    for i in range(len(num) // 2):
        num[len(num) // 2 + i] = num[len(num) // 2 - 1 - i]
    if int("".join(num)) > oldnum:
        print("".join(num))
    else:                  
#sometimes the palindrome was smaller eg: 1199 --> 1111
        num[len(num) // 2 - 1] = str(int(num[len(num) // 2 - 1]) + 1)
        num[len(num) // 2] = str(int(num[len(num) // 2]) + 1)
        print("".join(num))
else: #basically the same but for odd length numbers
    for i in range(len(num) // 2):
        num[len(num) // 2 + 1 + i] = num[len(num) // 2 - 1 - i]
    if int("".join(num)) > oldnum:
        print("".join(num))
    else:
        num[len(num) // 2] = str(int(num[len(num) // 2]) + 1)
        print("".join(num))
```

Comment: The question might be better suited here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use a profiler to find out where the time is spent first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would break it down,

```
# simple version, easy to understand and fast enough
#   up to maybe a thousand digits

def next_palindrome(n):
    """
    Find the first integer p such that p > n and p is palindromic
    """
    # There are two forms of palindrome:
    #   even number of digits,     abccba
    #   odd number of digits,      abcba
    # Find abc
    s = str(n)
    abc = s[:(len(s) + 1) // 2]

    # There are six possibilites for p:
    #    
    #   abcpq  <  abcba    -> p = abcba
    #   abcpq  >= abcba    -> p = ab(c + 1)ba      (with carries as needed)
    #   abcpqr == 999999   -> p = 1000001          *(num digits + 1)
    #  
    #   abcpqr <  abccba   -> p = abccba
    #   abcpqr >= abccba   -> p = ab(c+1)(c+1)ba   (with carries as needed)
    #   abcpq  == 99999    -> p = 100001           *(num digits + 1)
    #  
    #  *Note that the even-number-of-9s case is properly handled by
    #    odd-digits-with-carry, but odd-number-of-9s needs special handling
    #
    # Make basis substrings
    cba  = abc[::-1]
    ba   = cba[1:]
    abc1 = str(int(abc) + 1)
    cba1 = abc1[::-1]
    ba1  = cba1[1:]
    # Assemble candidate values
    candidates = [
        int(abc  + ba),        # abcba
        int(abc1 + ba1),       # ab(c+1)ba
        int(abc  + cba),       # abccba
        int(abc1 + cba1),      # ab(c+1)(c+1)ba
        int(abc1[:-1] + ba1)   # handles odd-number-of-9s
    ]
    # Find the lowest candidate > n
    return min(c for c in candidates if c > n)

def main():
    while True:
        n = int(input("\nValue for n (or -1 to quit): "))
        if n == -1:
            break
        else:
            print("Next palindrome is {}".format(next_palindrome(n)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which runs like

```
Value for n (or -1 to quit): 12301
Next palindrome is 12321

Value for n (or -1 to quit): 12340
Next palindrome is 12421

Value for n (or -1 to quit): 99999
Next palindrome is 100001

Value for n (or -1 to quit): 123001
Next palindrome is 123321

Value for n (or -1 to quit): 123400
Next palindrome is 124421

Value for n (or -1 to quit): 999999
Next palindrome is 1000001

Value for n (or -1 to quit): -1
```

---

**Edit:** I thought you were talking about maybe 100 digits. A million digits makes it worth spending more time minimizing the number of string operations and typecasts, like so:

```
# Super-efficient version
#  for playing with million-digit palindromes

def str_lt(x, y):
    """
    Take two integer strings, `x` and `y`,
      return int(`x`) < int(`y`)
    """
    return len(x) < len(y) or x < y

def str_add_1(n):
    """
    Given an integer string `n`,
      return str(int(n) + 1)
    """
    # find the first non-9 digit, starting from the right
    for i in range(len(n) - 1, -1, -1):
        if n[i] != '9':
            return n[:i] + str(int(n[i]) + 1) + '0' * (len(n) - i - 1)
    # string was all 9s - overflow
    return '1' + '0' * len(n)

def next_palindrome(n):
    """
    For non-negative integer `n` (as int or str)
      find the first integer p such that p > n and p is palindromic
    Return str(p)

    Note: `n` must be well-formed, ie no leading 0s or non-digit characters
    """
    # Make sure n is a string
    if not isinstance(n, str):
        n = str(n)

    # There are three forms of palindrome:
    #           single digit,      x    (ab == '')
    #  even number of digits,   abba    ( x == '')
    #   odd number of digits,  abxba    ( x is single digit)
    #    
    if len(n) == 1:
        # take care of single digit case
        return '11' if n == '9' else str_add_1(n)
    else:
        # There are six possibilites for p:
        #    
        #  (1)  abqr   <  abba   -> p = abba
        #  (2)  abqr  >=  abba   -> p = a(b+1)(b+1)a   (with carries as needed)
        #  (3)  abqr  ==  9999   -> p = 10001          (carry results in overflow)
        #  
        #  (4)  abxqr  < abxba   -> p = abxba
        #  (5)  abxqr >= abxba   -> p = ab(x + 1)ba    (with carries as needed)
        #  (6)  abxqr == 99999   -> p = 100001         (carry results in overflow)
        #
        # Find ab, x, qr
        half = len(n) // 2
        ab = n[     : half]
        x  = n[ half:-half]    # a 0- or 1-digit string
        qr = n[-half:     ]

        ba = ab[::-1]
        if str_lt(qr, ba):
            # solve cases (1) and (4)
            return "".join([ab, x, ba])

        if x == '9':
            # do manual carry from x
            ab1 = str_add_1(ab)
            ba1 = ab1[::-1]
            if len(ab1) > len(ab):
                # carry results in overflow - case (6)
                return ab1 + ba1
            else:
                # carry but no overflow - case (5)
                return "".join([ab1, '0', ba1])

        if x:
            # no carry - case (5)
            return "".join([ab, str_add_1(x), ba])

        # x == ''
        ab1 = str_add_1(ab)
        ba1 = ab1[::-1]
        if len(ab1) > len(ab):
            # carry results in overflow - case (3)
            return ab1[:-1] + ba1
        else:
            # no overflow - case (2)
            return ab1 + ba1
```

On my machine, this finds a million-digit palindrome in less than 0.002 seconds (vs about 18.5 seconds for your code).

Comment: This is helpful but produces an error for inputs 0-8 and is still too slow for numbers with 10^6 digits.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at it tonight.

Comment: This worked wonders. Could I ask what you do? I am learning python in school this year and am thinking of pursuing it. I was wondering how long it'll take for me to be around your level.

Comment: I've only been using Python for 3 or 4 years, but I have a long programming history before that; I started with a Vic-20 in 1981, and I think I've learned a new language every 2 or 3 years since then. Part of mastery is becoming really familiar with a language, its standard libraries and idioms; part is understanding algorithms and data structures and patterns, how to efficiently approach a problem; and part is having a range of experience in different language families and styles: assembly, declarative (Prolog or SQL), functional (Scala or Haskell), OO (Eiffel or Java), hardware (VHDL), etc.

Comment: Oh wow, so you'be been programming for almost 20 years more then I've been alive. Looks like I have a long way to go but I'll keep at it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code took less than a second for me. But why so much code for just finding a plaindrome. Why not simple do

```
def next_palindrome(num):
   while True:
       if str(num) == str(num)[::-1]:
           break
       num += 1
   return num
```

Comment: Because, if he gets his algorithm right, it will be O(log(n)) instead of O(sqrt(n)) - thousands of times faster for reasonably large input.

Comment: This becomes really slow when you have inputs with 10^6 digits